# Compile error for map operator []

Tags: c++, dictionary

Why do I get a compile error for "recMap[key] = rec;" in the below code but the equivalent statements work fine?  I have other code that does this.  What simple thing am I missing?

```
#include <map>

class MyRec {
   public:
   MyRec(int numberIn) : myNumber(numberIn) { };
   int myNumber;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   typedef std::map<int, MyRec> Recs;
   Recs recMap;
   int num=104702;
   int key=100923;

   MyRec rec(num);

   recMap[key] = rec; // Doesn't compile
   // error: no matching function for call to MyRec::MyRec()
   // samp.cpp:5: note: candidates are: MyRec::MyRec(int)
   // samp.cpp:3: note:                 MyRec::MyRec(const MyRec&)

   // Why do I receive the compile error for the above if it is the same as:
   (*((recMap.insert(std::make_pair(key,rec))).first)).second;

   recMap.insert(std::pair<int, MyRec>(key,rec)); // Works also of course
}
```

Comment: you need a default constructor and `operator<` for use in a `std::map`. The reason this particular line does not work is that when `recMap[key]` is evaluated, it does not have an entry, thus a "default" object is created and the reference is returned.

Comment: @crashmstr Isn't this worse as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Consider this snippet:

```
std::map<int, Foo> map;
map[0];
```

This will actually work fine even if havent inserted an object for key 0. The reason is, that there is a difference between `std::map::at()` and `std::map::operator []()`:

`std::map::at()` only returns a reference to an object inside the map. If there isnt an object for the given key, an exception is thrown.

`std::map::operator []()` does also return a reference, however if there no object for the given key, it **creates** an object inside the map and returns a reference to this newly created object. In order to create the object `std::map` must call the default constructor (a constructor with no additional arguments).

That is the reason why you code wont compile: Your class `MyRec` is not default constructable, but `std::map::operator []` requires this.

---

Thus you have three options:

1. Use `std::map::insert()`
2. Use `std::map::emplace()`
3. Make `MyRec` default constructable.

Comment: Okay so the default constructor makes the difference.  I see that.  I am a bit confused why it cannot just make a copy of the object I give it rather creating a default and filling it in.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you mention that you expect the `[] operator` to work the same as:

```
    (*((recMap.insert(std::make_pair(key,rec))).first)).second;
```

But it is **not** the same as that statement; rather it's the same as:

```
    (*((recMap.insert(std::make_pair(key,MyRec()))).first)).second;
```

Written like this, hopefully it's easier to see why the code doesn't compile (that is, MyRec does not define a [parameter-less constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultConstructible)).

Comment: But "rec" is a MyRec(), isn't it?  Are you saying it must be a default constructor?

Comment: @Pete Exactly, it needs a default constructor. As it is, "rec" isn't a `MyRec()`, it's a `MyRec(num)`.

Comment: @Pete When you assign a value using the [] operator, two things happen: 1) a new instance of MyRec is created (using the default constructor) and added to the map; 2) rec is copied into the map (overwriting the newly created value). This is counter-intuitive, but the reason it is necessary is because the [] operator has no knowledge of whether it's being used to read or write to the map; it only returns a reference to a location in the map. The insertion methods avoid this ambiguity, which allows you to directly add a copy of rec to the map without a default constructor.

Comment: this is not equivalent to the [] operator because insert won't insert the new value, if an existing key is found in the std::map